# How to creating custom dialog boxes with cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, dialog, cocos2d-iphone

1. top 
   http://i.imgur.com/LszAu.png
2. middle 
   http://i.imgur.com/j82Dr.png
3. bottom 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC5UE.png

dialog https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKw4g.png

How do i do with 1,2,3 to a dialog? And dialog can stretch with content? I hope you can write a simple example for me~~thanks!

Comment: The links don't work, just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a simple answer.
You need to create a custom layer and detect de text size to change the size of the layer.
(in the middle image you apply a scale, the others remains unchanged)

You can take a look at this tutorial:
[Custom Dialog Boxes Cocos2D](http://www.paullegato.com/blog/custom-dialog-boxes-cocos2d-iphone/)